# Cannot reference delegate protocols in implimentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIPickerView` that creates a string that I want to pass along to my RootViewController (*BL_MainViewController*).

My tactic was to use the delegate pattern but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong here. If my RootViewController is created using a Storyboard, how do I tell it *BL_MainViewController.BL_SetTimerViewController = self* and where do I set that in the implementation (guess:ViewDidLoad)?

**BL_SetTimerViewController.h** (the child VC presented by modal segue in IB)

```
@protocol BL_SetTimerViewControllerDelegate

-(void) updateLabelWithString:(NSString *)string;

@end

@interface BL_SetTimerViewController : UIViewController{
  ... // some ivars
}

@property (assign, nonatomic) id <BL_SetTimerViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**BL_SetTimerViewController.m**

```
@implementation BL_SetTimerViewController
...
@synthesize delegate;
...
- (IBAction)setTimerAndDismissViewController:(id)sender {

    // does some stuff, then:

    [self.delegate updateLabelWithString:@"TEST"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**BL_MainViewController.h** (The Root VC)

```
#import "BL_SetTimerViewController.h"

@interface BL_MainViewController : UIViewController <BL_SetTimerViewControllerDelegate>{
...
}


@end
```

**BL_MainViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // do some stuff here
    // presumably also assign the delegate protocol?
}

-(void)updateLabelWithString:(NSString *)string {
    self.pLabel.text = string;
}
```

Comment: you  missing prepare for segue with set delegate..

Answer (score 0):

In your  BL_MainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.pLabel.text=GlobleSting;
}

-(void)updateLabelWithString:(NSString *)string {
    GlobleSting = string; //declare in .h file
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YoursegueIdentifir"]) {
        BL_SetTimerViewController *settimerVC =
        segue.destinationViewController;
        settimerVC.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. After adding this method and just changing the identifier to @TimerSegueIdentifier, I clicked on the segue in IB and gave it the identifier string. But I'm not getting any changes... I should see "test" in the label.

Comment: Actually, it seems like it only works the first time it passes the values for some reason.

Comment: You should avoid global variables, especially for this case.

Comment: @TimurKuchkarov yeah, I definitely want to. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @Macness, I've added an answer. You might be missing something in your settings(or problem is somewhere else), because code looks correct.

Comment: please refers This link https://github.com/Ilesh/DelegatesTutorial/tree/master/DelegatesTutorial

Answer (score 0):

Super simple test app for delegate(note that many thing are left out as it's quickly thrown together), this works for me.(note that delegate is weak, not assign. If you are targeting iOS 5+, use weak for delegates)

SimpleProtocol.h

```
@protocol SimpleProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)updateText:(NSString *)text;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "SimpleProtocol.h"

@interface ViewController ()<SimpleProtocol>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *vc = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.delegate = self;
}

- (void)updateText:(NSString *)text
{
    self.label.text = text;
}

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SimpleProtocol.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(timerFire:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)timerFire:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %@", @(arc4random())];
    [self.delegate updateText:text];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```